# Modelbuilder Parameters - cannot select input files when model dialogue box is open

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, parameters

I created a model in modelbuilder and set the inputs to be parameters. When I open the model and the tool dialogue box shows up, the input files that I wish to select are not shown. These inputs are used for the "Select layer by location". Why is that and how do I fix it? I have all the input data set up in a geodatabase, and I can see it when I navigate to the .gdb in ArcCatalog.

Answer (score 3):

You've said you're using Select Layer By.... This tool requires a **layer** as input.
You said you've navigated to the data in ArcCatalog. ArcCatalog does not show **layers**, it shows the path to the data.

Use ArcMap, drag your data into the map, then open your tool. You should be able to chose the layer.

Comment: Connect your input FeatureClass to a Make FeatureLayer tool and the output of that is the input to your select by location tool